# Auditing Records In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-audited

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app which has a `Call` model with many different associations.  I want to be able to track changes to the `Call` model and somehow display a list of changes in the the `Call` Show View.

I've been reading about the [audited](https://rubygems.org/gems/audited/versions/3.0.0) gem which looks like it might do the trick.  But before I dive into this I'm wondering the following.

How can I call audits from within the show view?  I assume I can do something like passing a block:

`<% @call.audits.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.action %> <%= a.audited_changes %>
 <% end %>`

Will something like this work in the show view when I need to see changes made for a specific call?

How does the `audited` gem handle associations, especially `has_many_through`?

I'm looking to implement this feature soon but don't want to introduce any problems into my app.  I assume installing in a development environment might be the best route first?

If anyone has experience with this gem or can help provide answers, I'd really appreciate it.

**Update**
So I tried installing the audited gem and I was able to display the audit action and audited_changes.  But the format of audited_changes is a serialized hash.  How can I deserialize it and make the fields friendly?  Also it appears that the gem does not record changes when using a `has_many_through` relationship/join table.  So what I have now is a half-working audit gem with data that's not user friendly.  Any way to pretty this up and make it meaningful to the user?

**call.rb excerpt**

```
 has_many :call_units
  has_many :units, through: :call_units
  belongs_to :nature
  belongs_to :service_level
  belongs_to :patient_sex
  belongs_to :insurance
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :call_special_equipments
  has_many :special_equipments, :through => :call_special_equipments
  belongs_to :transferred_from, :foreign_key => :transfer_from_id, :class_name => 'Facility'
  belongs_to :transferred_to, :foreign_key => :transfer_to_id, :class_name => 'Facility'
  belongs_to :parent_call, class_name: "Call"
  has_many :notes
  belongs_to :cancel_reason
```

Comment: I see that your most recent edit is a year old, but have to ask: did you manage to display your audits in a readable manner? If not, I can help.

Comment: I know it's a long time now, but i can't seem to figure out how to display changes in an index page, i have `audited` added to the user model.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem for auditing record changes Here is another SO answer that shows how to display the record deltas: [Display all versions of individual records in Papertrail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653085/display-all-versions-of-individual-records-in-papertrail)

*No disparagement to the audited gem implied.*

Comment: Can you expand on how you did this?  Also including associated records and has many through relationships?

Comment: What are some of the associations you are wanting to track with the `Call` model? Can you add the relevant source code to your question?

Comment: Sure, I'll post up an excerpt of my call model.

Comment: I've posted up my associations from the `Call` model. I'm trying to track changes to polymorphic and `has_many_through` associations.  Can you provide an answer on how to implement paper_trail to track changes?  I'd really like to get this working.

Comment: @cz3ch - I'm working on a similar issue and have deduced, after a bit of research, that there is not an off the shelf solution for tracking changes on the associated models in a way that makes the presentation of those changes meaningful to a user. I'm electing to write a custom class that will track changes to the associated models and store them in a Papertrail metadata column in the parent model. It seems the best solution, but happy to be put right if others have a better solution.

Comment: @BetjaminRichards I am still working on this, but I ended up writing a custom class, model methods with call backs, and controller actions to make this work.  Logging `has_many_through` has proved very challenging as no of the shelf solution logs this sort of association.  Once I have it working, I'll post my code as an answer so you can get an idea of how I did it.  It's a very complex method and should be abstracted into a gem but this solution is very "custom" to my app and may not apply to everyone else.  Everything is stored in an Activities model using callbacks on the tracked model.

Answer (score 1):

We use something like this:

```
# app/views/audit_trail/index.html.haml
.table-responsive
  %table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Record
        %th Associated With
        %th By
        %th Action
        %th Changes
        %th Version
        %th Remote Address
        %th Timestamp

    %tbody
      = render @audits

# app/views/audited/adapters/active_record/audits/_audit.html.haml
%tr
  %td
    = "#{audit.auditable_type}:"
    %br
    = "'#{audit.auditable.try(:audited_friendly)}'"
  %td= audit.associated.try(:audited_friendly)
  %td= audit.user.try(:name)
  %td= audit.action
  %td= audit.audited_changes
  %td= audit.version
  %td= audit.remote_address
  %td= audit.created_at
```

Note that `audited_friendly` is a method we've added to models that are audited. So for example, a `User` model returns the `name` attribute but a `Pattern` model returns the `label` attribute.

**UPDATE**

Here are the relevant controller methods for both objects with audits (`User`) and audit records for objects associated with a record (`Client`):

```
# app/controllers/audits_controller.rb
  def index
    load_user if params[:user_id]
    load_client if params[:client_id]

    @audits = find_audits
  end

  def load_user
    @auditable = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def load_client
    @associated = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  end

  def find_audits
    if @auditable
      scope = @auditable.audits
    elsif @associated
      scope = Audited::Audit.where(associated_type: @associated.class.name, associated_id: @associated.id)
      scope = scope.where(auditable_type: params[:auditable_type]) if params[:auditable_type]
    end
    scope.reorder("id DESC, version DESC")
  end
```

Comment: could you please post the controller method here too